# Flutter configure credential

Tags: flutter

I'm a newbie in flutter and currently, I want to get the csrf key and value from server and then post back to backend together with the csrf key and value , but when I post the backend cannot make the key and value which mean the server not saving the csrf value that pass to me and I have done some research that need to add a credential setting when get the csrf value, But I have no idea on how to do it, is there anyone have some solution ? below is the get data code.

getData() async {

```
String profile = widget.url + "login";
var res = await http.get(profile, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
var resBody = json.decode(res.body);

csrfNameKey = resBody['data']['csrf_list']['csrf_name_key'];
csrfValueKey = resBody['data']['csrf_list']['csrf_value_key'];
csrfName = resBody['data']['csrf_list']['csrf_name'];
csrfValue = resBody['data']['csrf_list']['csrf_value'];

setState(() {
  print("Success");
  print(resBody);
  _loading = false;
});
```

}

Comment: whats the debug console saying? also you should replace {"Accept": "application/json"}
by
'content-type': 'application/json' do you want to pass the data from one widget to another?

Comment: just pass data to backend via url

Comment: debug not saying anything